# How to merge two boolean observables in ReactiveX

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.reactive

Recently was working with Rx and I'm having troubles with merging two observables and trying to make a command from them.

I have two observables, so I would like to make a command from them, and the commands can execute should be true only if those observables are true. Here is my code:

```
BuyCommand = playerData.Gold.Select(x => x >= boosterStoreItem.price)
            .Merge(inventoryItem.CanAddItem.Select(x => x))
            .ToReactiveCommand();
```

Well this code is kinda works, but the issue is, I have multiple BuyCommands (they are not sharing any observables between each other) and if any CanAddItem changes state, all BuyCommands CanExecute becoming true.

I believe I'm made a mistake with merging and that should be done in other way. So how should I fix it?

Note that it is UniRx (Rx for unity), but they are pretty much the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should work:

```
BuyCommand = playerData.Gold.Select(x => x >= boosterStoreItem.price)
            .CombineLatest(inventoryItem.CanAddItem.Select(x => x), (x,y) => x && y)
            .ToReactiveCommand();
```

`CombineLatest` combines two streams and publishes a value each time either sequence publishes one.  The value published is based on the result from the keySelector parameter, which in the example is `(x,y) => x && y`.  This means that the result will only be true if both streams result is true.